# Toolbar Issue after Backup Sp-Site

Tags: page-layout, backup, restore, toolbar

I am currently work on sharepoint 2013 on premise and i am a issue with full toolbar.

We got a test server where everything is ok and page got a custom page layout. Some page have a document library with full toolbar configuration.

After a backup Sp-Site with no issue during the process, all document library with full toolbar configuration don't show the "add document" button.

If we put summary tool bar configuration, everything show exactly like full toolbar option.

If everyone had the same issue or do you have some solution for me :)
I saw google link related to toolbar but no one work.

And if i put a library in the page with no custom layout it's ok.
The page layout is the same between the two server.
Thanks already.

I want the full toolbar configuration with the good display.